# How to return the sum of values from an array of objects based inside an array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, ecmascript-6

I have the following example array of objects, each object in the array contains an `id`, `personId`, `scores` and finally `score`. In some objects the `scores` is either `null` or it contains another array of objects which are the scores. In other objects the `score` may contain a value instead of being `null`. Finally, there may be a case when the object can contain both `scores` and `score`.

```
const startingArray = [
  {
    id: 1,
    personId: 1,
    scores: [
      {
        id: 1,
        title: 'Google',
        score: 12
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        title: 'Bing',
        score: 23
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        title: 'Facebook',
        score: 34
      }
    ],
    score: null
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    personId: 1,
    scores: null,
    score: 123
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    personId: 2,
    scores: [
      {
        id: 4,
        title: 'Google',
        score: 7
      },
      {
        id: 5,
        title: 'Bing',
        score: 32
      },
      {
        id: 6,
        title: 'Facebook',
        score: 9
      }
    ],
    score: null
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    personId: 3,
    scores: null,
    score: 106
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    personId: 3,
    scores: [
      {
        id: 7,
        title: 'Google',
        score: 6
      },
      {
        id: 8,
        title: 'Bing',
        score: 4
      },
      {
        id: 9,
        title: 'Facebook',
        score: 3
      }
    ],
    score: 5
  }
]
```

I can filter the `startingArray` to return the valid objects for a person:

```
startingArray.filter(item => item.personId === personId)
```

And I also figured out how to use `map` and `reduce` to return a value of the `score` items for the person:

```
startingArray.filter(item => item.personId === personId).map(item => item.score).reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0)
```

Where I'm struggling is to be able to sum the `score` items in the `scores` array where it's set against a person.

Ultimately what I'm after is to be able to call `personScores(1)` and it return the total of the scores for person 1 (i.e. 69), or call `personScores(3)` and it would return 124 (i.e. 106 + 13 + 5).

Comment: If you are expecting to find only a single person by id, you should have a look at `find` instead of `filter`. Then you'll get a single person object (or null) whose `.scores` you can access and reduce, not an array of (a single) persons.

Comment: What output do you expect for `personScores(5)`?

Comment: Why should person 1 return 69? The correct result according to person 3 would be 192 there

Comment: D-oh, you're correct Chris, I failed to notice that the object with `id:2` also had `personId:1`, so that would result in `69+123=192`. Thanks for pointing that out :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not clear whether a person can appear more than once in the `startingArray`. Assuming they can appear more than once:

One popular way to do it would be to use `Array#reduce`, but I'd just use a couple of `for-of` loops. You don't need to pre-`filter` (although some prefer to, which is fine).

Here's the `for-of` version:

```
function personScore(personId) {
  let sum = 0;
  for (const entry of startingArray) {
    if (entry.personId === personId) {
      sum += entry.score || 0;
      if (entry.scores) {
        for (const {score} of entry.scores) {
          sum += score;
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return sum;
}
```

Live Copy:

```js
const startingArray = [
  {
    id: 1,
    personId: 1,
    scores: [
      {
        id: 1,
        title: 'Google',
        score: 12
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        title: 'Bing',
        score: 23
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        title: 'Facebook',
        score: 34
      }
    ],
    score: null
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    personId: 1,
    scores: null,
    score: 123
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    personId: 2,
    scores: [
      {
        id: 4,
        title: 'Google',
        score: 7
      },
      {
        id: 5,
        title: 'Bing',
        score: 32
      },
      {
        id: 6,
        title: 'Facebook',
        score: 9
      }
    ],
    score: null
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    personId: 3,
    scores: null,
    score: 106
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    personId: 3,
    scores: [
      {
        id: 7,
        title: 'Google',
        score: 6
      },
      {
        id: 8,
        title: 'Bing',
        score: 4
      },
      {
        id: 9,
        title: 'Facebook',
        score: 3
      }
    ],
    score: 5
  }
]
function personScore(personId) {
  let sum = 0;
  for (const entry of startingArray) {
    if (entry.personId === personId) {
      sum += entry.score || 0;
      if (entry.scores) {
        for (const {score} of entry.scores) {
          sum += score;
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return sum;
}
console.log(personScore(1));
```

Here's the `reduce` version:

```
function personScore(personId) {
  return startingArray.reduce((sum, entry) => {
    if (entry.personId !== personId) {
      return sum;
    }
    sum += entry.score || 0;
    if (entry.scores) {
      sum += entry.scores.reduce((acc, {score}) => acc + score, 0);
    }
    return sum;
  }, 0);
}
```

Live Copy:

```js
const startingArray = [
  {
    id: 1,
    personId: 1,
    scores: [
      {
        id: 1,
        title: 'Google',
        score: 12
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        title: 'Bing',
        score: 23
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        title: 'Facebook',
        score: 34
      }
    ],
    score: null
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    personId: 1,
    scores: null,
    score: 123
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    personId: 2,
    scores: [
      {
        id: 4,
        title: 'Google',
        score: 7
      },
      {
        id: 5,
        title: 'Bing',
        score: 32
      },
      {
        id: 6,
        title: 'Facebook',
        score: 9
      }
    ],
    score: null
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    personId: 3,
    scores: null,
    score: 106
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    personId: 3,
    scores: [
      {
        id: 7,
        title: 'Google',
        score: 6
      },
      {
        id: 8,
        title: 'Bing',
        score: 4
      },
      {
        id: 9,
        title: 'Facebook',
        score: 3
      }
    ],
    score: 5
  }
]
function personScore(personId) {
  return startingArray.reduce((sum, entry) => {
    if (entry.personId !== personId) {
      return sum;
    }
    sum += entry.score || 0;
    if (entry.scores) {
      sum += entry.scores.reduce((acc, {score}) => acc + score, 0);
    }
    return sum;
  }, 0);
}
console.log(personScore(1));
```

If they can appear only once, an array really isn't the way to organize that data (I'd use an object or a `Map`), but with an array I'd use `find` to find them, and then just get the information from that one entry:

```
function personScore(personId) {
  const entry = startingArray.find(entry => entry.personId === personId);
  if (!entry) {
    return 0;
  }
  let sum = entry.score || 0;
  if (entry.scores) {
    for (const {score} of scores) {
      sum += score;
    }
  }
  return sum;
}
```

Live Copy:

```js
const startingArray = [
  {
    id: 1,
    personId: 1,
    scores: [
      {
        id: 1,
        title: 'Google',
        score: 12
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        title: 'Bing',
        score: 23
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        title: 'Facebook',
        score: 34
      }
    ],
    score: null
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    personId: 1,
    scores: null,
    score: 123
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    personId: 2,
    scores: [
      {
        id: 4,
        title: 'Google',
        score: 7
      },
      {
        id: 5,
        title: 'Bing',
        score: 32
      },
      {
        id: 6,
        title: 'Facebook',
        score: 9
      }
    ],
    score: null
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    personId: 3,
    scores: null,
    score: 106
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    personId: 3,
    scores: [
      {
        id: 7,
        title: 'Google',
        score: 6
      },
      {
        id: 8,
        title: 'Bing',
        score: 4
      },
      {
        id: 9,
        title: 'Facebook',
        score: 3
      }
    ],
    score: 5
  }
]
function personScore(personId) {
  const entry = startingArray.find(entry => entry.personId === personId);
  if (!entry) {
    return 0;
  }
  let sum = entry.score || 0;
  if (entry.scores) {
    for (const {score} of scores) {
      sum += score;
    }
  }
  return sum;
}
console.log(personScore(1));
```

Comment: Thanks, the `reduce` version is nice and neat and works.

Answer (score 1):

You can use reduce to get the sum and either use reduce again if we have an array for scores, or simply add what is at score

```js
function getPersonScore(arr, id) {
  const filtered = id ? arr.filter(e => e.personId === id) : arr;
  return filtered.reduce((a, b) => {
    if (Array.isArray(b.scores)) a += getPersonScore(b.scores);
    return a + (b.score || 0);
  }, 0);
}


console.log(getPersonScore(startingArray, 1));
```

```html
<script>
const startingArray = [
  {
    id: 1,
    personId: 1,
    scores: [
      {
        id: 1,
        title: 'Google',
        score: 12
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        title: 'Bing',
        score: 23
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        title: 'Facebook',
        score: 34
      }
    ],
    score: null
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    personId: 1,
    scores: null,
    score: 123
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    personId: 2,
    scores: [
      {
        id: 4,
        title: 'Google',
        score: 7
      },
      {
        id: 5,
        title: 'Bing',
        score: 32
      },
      {
        id: 6,
        title: 'Facebook',
        score: 9
      }
    ],
    score: null
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    personId: 3,
    scores: null,
    score: 106
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    personId: 3,
    scores: [
      {
        id: 7,
        title: 'Google',
        score: 6
      },
      {
        id: 8,
        title: 'Bing',
        score: 4
      },
      {
        id: 9,
        title: 'Facebook',
        score: 3
      }
    ],
    score: 5
  }
];
</script>
```

Comment: Chris, this is also an elegant way of doing it, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
const personScores = (id, arr) => {
  // error catching
  if (!Array.isArray(arr)) {
    throw new Error('Input array is not an array');
  }
  if (id >= arr.length) {
    throw new Error(`Id ${id} out of array range (length ${arr.length})`);
  }
  if (!('scores' in arr[id])) {
    throw new Error(`scores key missing in input array`);
  }
  if (!Array.isArray(arr[id].scores)) {
    throw new Error(`Scores of input id ${id} not an array`);
  }

  // iterate scores array of startingArray[id], defaultValue of sum is 0
  return arr[id].scores.reduce((sum, scoreObj) => {
    if ('score' in scoreObj && !isNaN(parseInt(scoreObj.score, 10))) {
      sum += parseInt(scoreObj.score, 10);
    }
    return sum;
  }, 0); // defaultValue of the reducer
};
```

Answer (score 0):

First `find` the person you want, then use `reduce` to add their `scores`, and finally add that to their `score`.

```js
const startingArray = [{id:1,personId:1,scores:[{id:1,title:'Google',score:12},{id:2,title:'Bing',score:23},{id:3,title:'Facebook',score:34}],score:null},{id:2,personId:1,scores:null,score:123},{id:3,personId:2,scores:[{id:4,title:'Google',score:7},{id:5,title:'Bing',score:32},{id:6,title:'Facebook',score:9}],score:null},{id:4,personId:3,scores:null,score:106},{id:5,personId:3,scores:[{id:7,title:'Google',score:6},{id:8,title:'Bing',score:4},{id:9,title:'Facebook',score:3}],score:5}];

const personScores = id => {
  let { scores, score } = startingArray.find(({ personId }) => personId);
  let finalScore = 0;
  if (score && score.length) finalScore += (Array.isArray(score) ? score.reduce((a, { score }) => a + score, 0) : score);
  if (scores && scores.length) finalScore += (Array.isArray(scores) ? scores.reduce((a, { score }) => a + score, 0) : scores);
  return finalScore;
};

console.log(personScores(1));
console.log(personScores(3));
```

<sub>(The above code checks both `score` and `scores` to see whether they are arrays or not, and performs the appropriate logic accordingly)</sub>